# Google Glass - 'Jump' to a card in CardScrollView?

Tags: android, google-glass, cardscrollview

I have a Google Glass app that uses a `CardScrollView` to display a series of Cards.

Touch gestures work to move between cards, but I need to be able to jump to specific cards by their index. I want to use contextual voice commands (ignore its limitations for now) to do this, for example: "ok glass, go to card 25".

I was hoping to be able to do something like this...

```
CardScrollView mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
    // ...
    // "ok glass, go to card 25"
    // ...
mCardScrollView.setFocus(25);
```

...But I can't seem to find a function to do that.

I didn't find anything on Google's reference page:  https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView

And their sample code doesn't cover this either:
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui-widgets#scrolling_cards_in_activities

I'd like to keep using `CardScrollView` if possible because I like the way it animates and scrolls compared to `ViewFlipper` or `ViewPager`. It's such a simple functionality that I believe should be there. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just having a similar issue. I was able to use mCardScrollView.setSelection(cardPosition) and it worked for m