# Google Glass - Handling arbitrary voice commands

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a Google Glass immersion that uses a `CardScrollView` to display a series of Cards.

I have created a `PanelMenu` that uses contextual voice commands by following Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#contextual_voice_commands).
I am able to jump to specific Cards using voice commands as described in a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922721/google-glass-jump-to-a-card-in-cardscrollview). The problem is I can only do this by creating a unique menu item for each card, like this:

```
// Voice-activated menu:
Go to Card 1
Go to Card 2
Go to Card 3
...
```

This is nice for a proof of concept but is impractical in any real situation. Can I get glass to recognize when I say an arbitrary number? This would ideally mean having a single "Go to Card" command in my menu and leave it clutter free. For example:

```
// Voice-activated menu:
Go to Card X
```

Where `X` can be any integer `1,2,3...`

---

All put together, I would like the interaction to go like this:

```
1) App opens, displays Card 1

2) User says "ok glass"

3) PanelMenu opens, it displays one item: 'Go to Card'

4) User says "Go to Card 6"

5) App displays Card 6

// reopen PanelMenu...

6) User says "Go to Card 22"

7) App displays Card 22
```

[Issue 273](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273) has numerous links regarding Contextual Voice Commands, but I can't seem to find anything like what I have described. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like to me is that you want contextual voice commands, as you mentioned. The developer page has a nice example describing how you can develop such a feature. Read up on the page [Voice Input](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice) and see how they are doing. They have an example about showing dogs in a way where you have to say "ok, glass", "show me dogs", "labrador" and it will then - if programmed correctly - bring up information about labradors.

I hope that answered your question.